# Jssor (Slider-cluster): Child slide's arrow navigation and caption transition not showing up properly

Tags: jquery, jssor

1) Arrow Navigation:

I have large (child) slides that scale to full size of the browser window instead of the those shown in the example on http://www.jssor.com/demos/slider-cluster.html

Probably due to that, the Arrow Navigator doesn't appear even I had set $ChanceToShow to 2 (Always). In order to make it appear, I have to mouse-out of the slide area and then back in, which is not intuitive to users.

2) Caption Transition:

My issues with the Child slide's caption transition is that when the captions either 1. Did not animate after the slide appear or 2. when they do animate (usually after I navigate between the child slides), the caption can disappear altogether. The following are sample codes I used for one of the child slides.

```
    <!-- Slides Container -->

<div u="slides" style="cursor: auto; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 2000px; height: 800px; overflow: hidden;">

  <div>
    <img src="../img/01a.jpg"/>
    <div u="caption" t="T" t2="B" d="-300" class="bodytxt" style="position:absolute; top:500px; left:525px; width:850px; height:80px; background-position: 0px -165px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="../img/01b.jpg"/>
    <div u="caption" t="T" t2="B" d="-300" class="bodytxt" style="position:absolute; top:600px; left:525px; width:850px; height:80px; background-position: 0px -165px;"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Anyone can help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that issue 1 (Arrow Navigation not appearing on Child slides) only occurred on Chrome, but seems fine on Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea at the moment. Maybe you can set option $HWA to false.
Would you please leave an url or send me your work?
Thanks!

Comment: I have made further observation. 1) The Arrow Navigation did not appear on the child slides if a caption <div> was not included after the slider code. So as long as I added a caption div, then it's ok. 2) The child slides' captions seem to disappear after I clicked other parent slides then enter the slide with the child slides again. Probably because these captions did not 'properly exit' the child slides? You can also see the captions within the child slide disappear if you browse the slides here: http://www.jssor.com/demos/slider-cluster.html. Is there any way to overcome these? Thank you.

Comment: I noticed that there is problem of slider cluster.I will investigate on it later. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Btw, am I able to track the various slides and/or click throughs using Google Analytics? Thanks again for your great effort.

Comment: I guess yes. Everything in slider is the same as other elements in your page.